# ¿Cómo puedo enviar un puntero como parámetro y que este sea modificado en la función a la que es enviado?

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, punteros

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

Estructura de la que se forma el arbol binario

```
typedef struct NodoArbol {
  int valor;
    struct NodoArbol* derecho;
    struct NodoArbol* izquierdo;
} sNodoArbol, *sNodoArbol_ptr;

struct NodoArbol* arbolBinario = NULL;
```

Función que asigna y crea los valores de las estructuras
el problema es que como es recursiva necesito mandar como parámetro la raíz del árbol pero envía una copia por lo que el puntero original no es modificado.

```
void insertar(int valor, sNodoArbol_ptr raiz) {
    if (raiz == NULL) {
        raiz = (struct NodoArbol*) malloc (sizeof(struct NodoArbol));
        raiz->valor = valor;
        raiz->derecho = NULL;
        raiz->izquierdo = NULL;
    } else if (valor <= raiz->valor) {
        insertar(valor, raiz->izquierdo);
    } else {
        insertar(valor, raiz->derecho);
    }
}
```

Función que imprime el contenido del árbol

```
void printPosOrden(sNodoArbol_ptr raiz) {
    if (raiz == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    printPosOrden(raiz->izquierdo);
    printPosOrden(raiz->derecho);
    printf(" %d -> ", raiz->valor);
}

int main() {
    insertar(56, arbolBinario);
    printPosOrden(arbolBinario);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> *necesito mandar como parámetro la raíz del árbol pero envía una copia por lo que el puntero original no es modificado*

Cuando pasas un valor a una función por valor siempre pasas una copia del valor como argumento, lo que tu quieres hacer es pasar [un valor por referencia](https://parzibyte.me/blog/2018/09/20/funciones-referencia-valor-c/).

En C para pasar un parámetro por referencia debes de pasarlo como un puntero y como lo que ya estás pasando es un puntero podrías trabajarlo como un puntero doble.

Mira este ejemplo en donde utilizo tu estructura, inicializo un objeto con la misma y creo un puntero que apunte a ella. Luego paso este puntero a una función por medio de una referencia (en vez de pasar una copia) y puedo editar el elemento original:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct NodoArbol {
  int valor;
    struct NodoArbol* derecho;
    struct NodoArbol* izquierdo;
} sNodoArbol, *sNodoArbol_ptr;

sNodoArbol* arbolBinario = NULL;

void cambiarValor(int valor, sNodoArbol ** raiz) {
    sNodoArbol * nuevaRaiz = (sNodoArbol *) malloc (sizeof(sNodoArbol));
    nuevaRaiz->valor = valor;
    nuevaRaiz->derecho = NULL;
    nuevaRaiz->izquierdo = NULL;
    *raiz = nuevaRaiz;
}

int main() {
    cambiarValor(0, &arbolBinario);
    printf(" arbolBinario->valor:%d\n", arbolBinario->valor);
    cambiarValor(56, &arbolBinario);
    printf(" arbolBinario->valor:%d\n", arbolBinario->valor);
    return 0;
}
```

Resultado:

```
arbolBinario->valor:0                                                                                                  
arbolBinario->valor:56
```

Como ya haces un `typedef struct` puedes simplemente utilizar `sNodoArbol` para hacer referencia a la estructura. También puedes utilizar la referencia que haces al tipo puntero y quedaría así (es equivalente al primer ejemplo):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct NodoArbol {
  int valor;
    struct NodoArbol* derecho;
    struct NodoArbol* izquierdo;
} sNodoArbol, *sNodoArbol_ptr;

sNodoArbol_ptr arbolBinario = NULL;

void cambiarValor(int valor, sNodoArbol_ptr * raiz) {
    sNodoArbol_ptr nuevaRaiz = (sNodoArbol_ptr) malloc (sizeof(sNodoArbol));
    nuevaRaiz->valor = valor;
    nuevaRaiz->derecho = NULL;
    nuevaRaiz->izquierdo = NULL;
    *raiz = nuevaRaiz;
}

int main() {
    cambiarValor(0, &arbolBinario);
    printf(" arbolBinario->valor:%d\n", arbolBinario->valor);
    cambiarValor(56, &arbolBinario);
    printf(" arbolBinario->valor:%d\n", arbolBinario->valor);
    return 0;
}
```

Lo pongo de las dos maneras para que veas que es lo que está pasando.